# Get Y-position of box collider BORDERS

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

First some background info, I am making a mobile application similar to Flappy Bird, except its voice controlled. The idea is to have this app as a practice tool for people with voice problems (monotony). The bird flies upwards when the user makes a high pitch, and downwards when it's a low pitch.

The app is linked to a website where the vocal coach can follow the user's progress. For this purpose, I am saving data about the user's game performance into a database. More specifically, every time the bird passes through a pipe opening, I save the pitch values that he correctly produced, along with the two "threshold pitch values" that represent the upper and lower borders of the pipe opening.

My pipes are Prefabs generated by a Parallaxer script. The Prefab object consists of three childs:

1. Sprite for the top pipe  (with a box collider)
2. A box collider representing the pipe opening
3. Sprite for the bottom pipe (with a box collider)

Now I need to access the Y-positions of the upper border and lower border of the pipe opening. The solution that I have tried uses Raycasts. I cast two rays, both starting from the Prefab Object's position. Since the pipe opening (box collider) is in the middle of the prefab, both rays start **within** the box collider. One ray goes upwards and is supposed to collide with the upper border, and the other goes downwards and is supposed to collide with the lower border. But the returned positions are just the exact same as the start point... So I assume raycasts actually return the **position of the collider itself** that they hit, not the **position of where it actually hit**. I am not sure about my statement, but only this would explain why it is not working. Here's an illustration of the problem (made with paint): https://prnt.sc/npcckq

I'm also providing my current code:

```
Debug.Log("Spawn position of pipe is " + t.position.y);  //Gives ex. 4.58
RaycastHit2D hit1 = Physics2D.Raycast(t.position, Vector2.up);
RaycastHit2D hit2 = Physics2D.Raycast(t.position, -Vector2.up);
if (hit1.collider != null && hit2.collider != null)
{
        Debug.Log("Upper border: " + hit1.point.y); //Also gives 4.58
        Debug.Log("Lower border: " + hit2.point.y); //Also gives 4.58
}
```

I'd appreciate any help to make this work, or even another solution that would be easier than using Raycasts!

Comment: I believe you have something like collider.point or similar (or a method to get contact point). Not in front of unity right now, but I'm pretty sure I already used this

Comment: @Jichael Would you mind checking when possible, and come back to me with the answer please?

Comment: Are you able to verify that the raycast is hitting the pipes and not the player itself from the inside? Verify that the raycast is scanning a layer in which only the pipes exist. You're already using hit.point so you should be getting the exact position of the point of contact.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard I cannot verify what the raycasts are hitting... But I can guarantee 100% it is not the player that they hit. I call the raycasts inside my pipe's Spawn() method. As they spawn somewhere far off to the left of the screen, it can't hit the player. And I start the raycasts from the inside of the middle box collider on purpose (see screenshot in my question post), so the first thing they hit **should** be the upper/lower border of that same box collider.

Comment: @M.Benamar On the Collision component, there is a property contacts which is an array of Contact points, and methods GetContact and GetContacts to get one or more contact point.

Comment: You can verify what the raycast is hitting by following the tree back up to the gameObject. Use hit.collider.gameobject.tag. Log it in the console and see what happens. Also, try enabling the gizmo in the editor which will show you the actual raycasts as lines in the Scene viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the info in comments I think the approach with raycast could be not working because there are too many colliders. Consider also that if you start a raycast INSIDE a collider the raycast will hit at once.

So a better option would be to use collider bounds.
Consider that this approach require the collider to be on the same script of the game object.

Set the collider you want to check in the fields of the class, and pass it in the inspector window.

```
public BoxCollider2D_colliderToCheck;
```

I split the code in 2 sections.

### 1 Find the collider

You can find the collider by using this.

```
//get the collider
var collider = _colliderToCheck.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
```

If you have more colliders you may use tags like this.

```
BoxCollider2D _colliderToCheck = null;

var colliders = GetComponentsInChildren<BoxCollider2D>(true);

for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
    if (colliders[i].transform.CompareTag("DesiredTag"))
        _colliderToCheck = colliders[i];
```

### 2 Find the boundaries

```
//get the extents
var yHalfExtents = collider.bounds.extents.y;
//get the center
var yCenter = collider.bounds.center.y;
//get the up border
float yUpper = transform.position.y + (yCenter + yHalfExtents);
//get the lower border
float yLower = transform.position.y + (yCenter - yHalfExtents);
Debug.Log("Upper border: " + yUpper );
Debug.Log("Lower border: " + yLower );
```

### PREVIOUS BACKUP

From what I see you send 2 raycast, one goes down while the other goes up, but the origin is the same (`t.position`).

[Physics2D.Raycast - Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

The first thing I would do is trying to change the position of the origin of the raycast.

You can achieve that by doing this.

```
RaycastHit2D hit1 = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(t.position.x, t.position.y-100), Vector2.up);
RaycastHit2D hit2 = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(t.position.x, t.position.y+100), -Vector2.up);
if (hit1.collider != null && hit2.collider != null)
{
        Debug.Log("Upper border: " + hit1.point.y);
        Debug.Log("Lower border: " + hit2.point.y);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it seems to just give the position value + 5, and position -5...

Comment: How large is the collider? Are there other colliders around? You may try using 100 instead of 5. Maybe also use a LayerMask.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the screenshot in my question post? I also explained my pipe prefab object's hierarchy. Yes there's other colliders around (the top pipe and the bottom pipe). But it shouldn't matter as my raycasts start from the middle of the opening **on purpose** so that the first thing they hit are the opening's borders. Here's another screenshot of my Unity Editor, I dragged a pipe prefab object onto the scene, and I'm also showing the size of the middle boxcollider (called ScoreZone on the screen): http://prntscr.com/npj8fq

Comment: Raycast won't work if it start inside a collider. And if you have that many colliders you will most likely hit another one. So another approach is to use the bounds of the collider. This works ONLY with BoxCollider2D (well, also with other, but you need to change the code.) I updated the answer with the new info.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I hope this solution will work, but before trying I'd like to confirm something. Looking at the documentation for `bounds.extents`it states "The extents of the Bounding Box. This is **always half of the size** of the Bounds." Isn't this exactly what you tried to achieve with `yHalfExtents`? Meaning we could simply just do `float yUpper = transform.position.y + (yCenter + collider.bounds.extents.y);`?

Comment: Also another problem, I don't know how I can access the middle collider as my gameObject has 3 children box colliders (top pipe, middle opening, bottom pipe)

Comment: Yes. You're right, the extents are already halved. Try to check this in the code, but I think you won't need the /2 division. How to access the collider: easier way is to add a `public collider _colliderToCheck` and use it for checking. Answer updated.

Comment: I can't make use of public variables and drag into editor... The pipes are being randomly spawned by a Parallaxer script

Comment: Can you add them in a prefab? Otherwise you could use a [tag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EA54-vfLkUI) on the required collider and get the tag?

Comment: Oh, I do use tags! The middle collider has a tag "ScoreZone" and the top and bottom pipes both use "DeadZone" tag. Since the middle collider has a distinguished tag, can I access it through it?

Comment: I added the tag example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `LayerMask` to the Raycast method, and then in `Editor/Project Settings` you can see the physics layer matrix to tell which layers can hit the others, make `Layer1` hit only `Layer2` and `Layer2` hit only `Layer1` and its done.

Comment: Thanks, but being quite new to Unity I don't understand how I should put that into actual code. 1) Which elements of my Scene should be in Layer1? 2) Which ones should be in Layer2? 3) What Layer should I give as parameter to the Raycast method?